# Django, article and categories migrate perfectly but after it error " relation doesn't exit "

Tags: django

I am creating a press page with articles etc.

So, an article has a source (category). And then multiple article can have the same source or many.

I divided it in two classes :

```
@version_controlled_content
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ArticleSource(TranslatableModel):
  taints_cache = True

  date_created = models.DateTimeField(_('created at'), auto_now_add=True)
  date_modified = models.DateTimeField(_('modified at'), auto_now=True)
  position = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
  translations = TranslatedFields(
    name=models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=510),
    slug=models.SlugField(_('slug'), blank=True, db_index=True),
    meta={'unique_together': (('language_code', 'slug'),)},
  )
  objects = TranslationManager()

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('Press source')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Press sources')
    ordering = ('position', )

  @property
  def count(self):
    return self.press_article.filter(publish=True).count()

  def __str__(self):
    name = self.safe_translation_getter('name', any_language=True)
    return name if name is not None else '(not translated)'

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ArticleSource, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    for lang in self.get_available_languages():
        self.set_current_language(lang)
        if not self.slug and self.name:
            self.slug = slugify(force_text(self.name))
    self.save_translations()


@version_controlled_content
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Article(ModelMeta, TranslatableModel):
  taints_cache = True

  """
  Press article element,
  """
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  date_realization = models.DateField(_('Realised in'),
                                     default=timezone.now)
  image = FilerImageField(verbose_name=_('Featured image'), blank=True,
                             null=True,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             related_name='image_press_article',
                             help_text=_('Set if the article will be featured'))

  sources = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleSource, verbose_name=_('Source'),
                                    blank=False, null=True, related_name='sources_press_article')

  regions = models.ManyToManyField(Country, verbose_name=_('Country of the article'),
                                 blank=True, null=True,
                                 related_name='regions_press_article')

  global_regions = models.BooleanField('Global', default=False)

  featureArticle = models.BooleanField('Feature this article', default=False)

  sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site, verbose_name=_('Sites'), blank=True,
                                                    null=True,
                                                    help_text=_('Select sites in which show the project.'))

  article_url = models.CharField(_('Article Url'), max_length=310, blank=False,
                                   help_text=_('Use to link to the original source'))

  position = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
....
```

The admin is a standard one :

```
class ArticleAdmin(MultisiteAdminMixin,
               VersionedPlaceholderAdminMixin,
               FrontendEditableAdminMixin,
               SortableAdminMixin,
               TranslatableAdmin):

def sites_visible_on(self, obj):
    return ', ' .join('%s' % site.name for site in obj.sites.all())

def countries_visible_on(self, obj):
    qs = obj.countries_displayed_in.all()
    if not len(qs):
        return _('All')

    return ', ' .join('%s' % country.name
                      for country in obj.countries_displayed_in.all())

sites_visible_on.short_description = _('Sites visible on')
countries_visible_on.short_description = _('Countries visible from')

list_display = [
    '__str__', 'date_realization',
    'sites_visible_on', 'countries_visible_on',
    'language_column',
    'featureArticle'
]

search_fields = ('translations__title',)
date_hierarchy = 'date_realization'
frontend_editable_fields = ('title', 'source', 'description')
list_per_page = 10
fieldsets = [
    ('Archive article', {
        'fields': [('title', 'sources'), ('slug', 'date_realization'), ('regions', 'global_regions'), 'article_url']
    }),
    ('Feature', {
        'fields': ('featureArticle', 'image', 'description'),
    }),

    ('Localization', {
        'fields': ('sites', 'countries_displayed_in'),
        'classes': ('collapse',)
    }),
    ('SEO', {
        'fields': [('meta_description', 'meta_title', 'meta_keywords')],
        'classes': ('collapse',)
    }),
]

def get_prepopulated_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    return {'slug': ('title',)}

class ArticleSourceAdmin(VersionedPlaceholderAdminMixin,
                       FrontendEditableAdminMixin,
                       SortableAdminMixin,
                       TranslatableAdmin):
list_display = ['__str__', 'language_column']

def get_prepopulated_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    return {'slug': ('name',)}
```

admin.site.register(ArticleSource, ArticleSourceAdmin)
admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)

So, everything is displaying correctly except 2 case :

1. If I want to add an Article I will have :

   > Relation "djangocms_press_articlesource" does not exist
   >   LINE 1: ..., "djangocms_press_articlesource"."position" FROM "djangocms...
2. If I create a new source and save it, I have the same error showing

So I start to feel without option, the migration file seems to be correct about articleSource... :

```
migrations.CreateModel(
        name='ArticleSource',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(serialize=False, primary_key=True, verbose_name='ID', auto_created=True)),
            ('date_created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='created at')),
            ('date_modified', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='modified at')),
            ('position', models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name_plural': 'Press sources',
            'ordering': ('position',),
            'verbose_name': 'Press source',
        },
        bases=(models.Model,),
    ),
```

Well, I am completely lost, it was working fine this way with a showroom application, but not this time apparently.

Comment: If you run `manage.py migrate yourapp zero` and then re-run `manage.py migrate your_app` - does it print out that it has created the `ArticleSource` model?

Comment: In fact, it only writes : Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: djangocms_press

Comment: Okay, then goto `zero` one more time and try the migrations one-by-one, e.g. `manage.py migrate your_app 0001` and so forth.

Comment: Ok, btw when I do the zero, I have the error poping : psycopg2.ProgrammingError: table "djangocms_press_article_sources" does not exist

Comment: So after your manipulation : 

Operations to perform:
  Target specific migration: 0001_initial, from djangocms_press
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Comment: As your `zero` migration doesn't succeed, the following steps don't either. Try `migrate zero --fake` to completely fool Django ). And then run migrations one-by-one.

Comment: Awesome (and really weird), it works !
If you have any explication about it and / or write the answer, I could approve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today is the day of migrations' woes - I've just answered a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794837/tables-not-created-for-django-app/34795775#34795775).

So, in your case Django somehow thinks it already created the tables, but in fact it didn't. To re-run migrations, you should make Django think it has not yet run any migrations by executing:

```
manage.py migrate yourapp zero --fake
```

Then apply your migrations one-by-one to track any errors:

```
manage.py migrate yourapp 0001
manage.py migrate yourapp 0002
```

and so on. Be careful though, as you very probably could lose your data. Backup always does the trick.